# Getting an error while deriving class from std::exception

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

[image]I am deriving a class from std::exception but i got an error 
Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class exp1 : public std::exception {
public:
    exp1() noexcept = default;
    ~exp1() = default;
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return "This is an exception";
    }
};


int main()
{
    try{
        int i; 
        cin >> i;
        if(i == 0)throw exp1() ;
        else {cout << i << endl;}
       }
    catch(exp1 & ex){
        cout << ex.what() << endl; 
       }
return 0;
}
```

My code is working fine but when i include `noexcept` to the constructor

```
exp1() noexcept = default;
```

then i get the errors

```
'exp1::exp1(void) noexcept': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

and

```
the declared exception specification is incompatible with the generated one
```

Comment: What compiler?  What compiler version?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: i am using VS2015

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what is the problem in my code ? I am using VS2015

Comment: Works fine for gcc/clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12cc8a82d4488fd3).

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd suspect in VC2015 implementation the default constructor of `std::exception` is not marked `noexcept`. `exp1` default constructor calls it, and so can't be `noexcept` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified your constructor of class `exp1` as being `noexcept`and `default`. This means that the compiler will generate a constructor for you. While doing so it inherits the exception specification of the parent class (if any).

According to the C++ standard, std::exception should have a `noexcept` constructor and if this would have been the case in your situation you wouldn't have had this compiler error. However, the first versions of Visual Studio 2015 didn't meet the C++ standard and that's why you got this compiler error.

Later versions of Visual Studio 2015 comply to the C++ standard and won't trigger a compiler error any more. I have tested this with Visual Studio 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and your code compiles fine.

So if you still encounter this problem, then please upgrade to a later version of Visual Studio 2015.